# How to nest httpclient calls wrapped in APP_INITIALIZER

Tags: angular, typescript, httpclient

I've implemented a httpCall that is triggered by APP_INITIALIZER and it returns a  URL which I then want to use for another nested httpCall:

```
getAppSettings(): Observable<IAppSettings> {
    return (this.httpClient
        .get<IAppSettings>(this.localbaseUrl)
        .pipe(
            catchError(this.errorHandlerSerevice.handleError)
        )) as any;
}

getConfigValues(): Promise<void> {
    return this.getAppSettings()
        .toPromise()
        .then(data => {
            this.exampleUrl = data;
            this.getOtherStuff().subscribe(data => this.stuff = data);
        });
}

getOtherStuff(): Observable<any[]> {
    return (this.httpClient
        .get<any[]>(this.exampleUrl)
        .pipe(
            catchError(this.errorHandlerSerevice.handleError)
        )) as any;
}
```

This implementation is wrong and on page refresh it throws the following error:

```
 Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

which comes from  this.stuff[] not being populated in time (second, nested httpClient observable call).

How do I properly implement/nest those httpClient calls. 
Please notice I use Angular 6 and httpClient, please do not suggest the old http get solutions.

Comment: The error doesn't seem to align with the code that you've shared. How would someone get an idea as to what exactly is it checking for the `length` property on?

Comment: Right, apologies. 
this.stuff is any[] and the error is thrown on the page refresh. 
The code works fine the first time I load the application. So it looks like on the refresh the this.stuff is not populated. 
Do you think the calls are wired in in a proper way?

Comment: Leave here another way https://ng-run.com/edit/J9khrvXLmu3jvfQ4h9lV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can't nest an Observable in a Promise initialised by APP_INITIALIZER. the nested call also needs to be a Promise. See the modified method that now correctly assigns the this.stuff:

```
getConfigValues(): Promise<void> {
    return this.getAppSettings()
        .toPromise()
        .then(data => {
            this.exampleUrl = data;
        }).then(() => {
                return this.getOtherStuff()
                    .toPromise()
                    .then(data => { 
                            this.stuff = data; 
                    });
            }
        );
}
```